# Sort Multiple XML Files By Date

Tags: php

I have a news widget that uses DOM Xml to pull in multiple xml files to display. I am trying to figure out how to get the articles to display in order by date. Here is the code for the widget:

```
$dh = opendir('./xml/');
    $fileCount = 0;
    while ($file = readdir($dh) and $fileCount < 3) {
    if (preg_match("/^..?$/", $file)) {
        continue;
    }
    $open = "./xml/".$file;
    $xml = domxml_open_file($open);
    //we need to pull out all the things from this file that we will need to 
    //build our links
    $root = $xml->root();
    $stat_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("status");
    $status = extractText($stat_array);
    $date_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("date");
    $date = extractText($date_array);
    $ab_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("abstract");
    $abstract = extractText($ab_array);
    $h_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("headline");
    $headline = extractText($h_array);
    $img_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("image");
    $image = extractText($img_array);
    $lead_array = $root->get_elements_by_tagname("para-intro");

    $para["intro"] = extractText($lead_array);

    if ($status != "live") {
        continue;
    }

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-12 newsbox\"><img style=\"margin-bottom: 10px;\" width=\"100%\" src=\"images/news/".$image."\"><div class=\"newsboxtext\"><a href=\"showArticle.php?file=".$file. "\"><h2 class=\"mainheadline2\"> ".$headline . "</h2></a><a href=\"showArticle.php?file=".$file . "\"><button  style=\"margin-top:5px;\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\">+ Read More</button></a></div><hr class=\"linedivider\">
</div>";

    $fileCount++;
}
```

And this is what I was using to try and sort the results:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $date1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $date2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $date1 - $date2;
}    
usort($file, 'date_compare');
```

but I received this error. Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: $file in this case is a handle and not an array.  You could create an array in your while loop $array[] = $file; and that should work.

Comment: Tried that. Now I'm getting this error: Cannot redeclare date_compare()

Comment: First validate that $file is an array and is what you are expecting.  That error means that function has already been declared so either it has already been declared somewhere in your program OR more likely, maybe it is inside your loop?

Comment: I did have the function inside the loop. I moved it below the loop and it now displays the 3 main articles but is not sorting them by date.

Comment: make sure that date1 - date2 is a positive number because it uses an intval  and a negative number will result in all being 0.  you may just have to do the reverse date2 - date1 (Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.)

Comment: I'm alittle confused. The date in my xml files is formatted like this YYYY-MM-DD. Should I be using a different format?

Comment: right, but you are changing the date to a time string with strtotime() within the date_compare function.

Comment: Still having issues. Should I be using something other then $file to create the array? Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is for the xml files (each article is its own xml file) to be returned with the most recent article on top based on the date that I input into the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing all extracted tag values into a multidimensional array, `$xmlData`, then sort the array, then echo web html data from sorted array:

```
$r = 0;
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

function extractText($tag) {
   foreach ($tag as $item) {
      $value = $item->nodeValue;
   }
   return $value;
}

while ($file = readdir($dh) and $fileCount < 3) {

    if (preg_match("/^..?$/", $file)) {
        continue;
    }

    $open = "./xml/".$file;
    $xml->load($open);

    //we need to pull out all the things from this file that we will need to 
    //build our links
    $xmldata = [];
    $xmldata[$r]['file'] = $file;

    $stat_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("status");
    $xmldata[$r]['status'] = extractText($stat_array);

    $date_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("date");
    $xmldata[$r]['date']= extractText($date_array);

    $ab_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("abstract");
    $xmldata[$r]['abstract'] = extractText($ab_array);

    $h_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("headline");
    $xmldata[$r]['headline'] = extractText($h_array);

    $img_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("image");
    $xmldata[$r]['image'] = extractText($img_array);

    $lead_array = $xml->getElementsByTagName("para-intro");
    $xmldata[$r]['paraintro'] = extractText($lead_array);

    if ($status != "live") {
        continue;
    }

    $fileCount++;
    $r++;
}

// YYYY-MM-DD STRINGS STILL SORTS IN DAILY ORDER (I.E., '2015-01-01' < '2015-12-31')
usort($xmldata, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['date'], $b['date']);
});

$xmlcount = sizeof($xmldata[0]);

// ITERATE THROUGH LOOP EVERY NEEDED ITEM IN SORT ORDER OF ARRAY
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($xmlcount - 1); $i++) {

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-12 newsbox\">
           <img style=\"margin-bottom: 10px;\" width=\"100%\" src=\"images/news/".$xmldata[$i]['image']."\">
            <div class=\"newsboxtext\">
              <a href=\"showArticle.php?file=".$xmldata[$i]['file']. "\">
                <h2 class=\"mainheadline2\"> ".$xmldata[$i]['headline']. "</h2>
              </a>
              <a href=\"showArticle.php?file=".$xmldata[$i]['file']. "\">
                <button  style=\"margin-top:5px;\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\">+ Read More</button>
              </a>
            </div><hr class=\"linedivider\">
          </div>";

}
```

Comment: Tried using this  but it is giving me this error. Illegal string offset 'file' in

Comment: Fortunately, that's at the end in `echo` command. See edit where I changed the `for` loop and rendered `$xmldata` a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the above changes and I am now getting Undefined index: date

Comment: See new edit. The `usort()` function did not like the new multi-dimensional array. I had to even redefine `$xmldata` and I removed the anonymous 'date compare' function as you don't need it if working with PHP 5.3+. Finally, since we leave date as string, `strcmp()` is used to order.

Comment: Now I' getting an `Undefined Offset` Error. Could this bit of code describing the extract text function be causing a problem? `function extractText($array){
 if(count($array) <= 1){
  //we only have one tag to process!
  for ($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++){
   $node = $array[$i];
   $value = $node->get_content();
  }
  return $value;
 } 
}`

Comment: What line does error point to? See my edit using PHP 5+ DOM document extension and no longer the PHP 4 domxml extension. Now `load()`, `getElementsByTagName()`, and `nodeValue()` are used with latter inside a new user defined `extractText()` function.

Comment: I noticed there was two lines of script that were cut off on my original post `$dh = opendir('./xml/'); $fileCount = 0;` . I'm receiving the error `Undefined variable: item` on line 9. Then `Undefined Offset` on 65,67, 68, and 70.

Comment: At this point, you have a working example. I don't know enough of your environment or full intentions to specifically resolve. Please try amending my proposed solution to your needs. Fundamentally, see how I changed the process from your initial setup and integrate accordingly.